# New Subversion SVN repository not showing up without restart

Tags: svn

I'm running Subversion SVN on a Windows 2003 box running Apache and something called "WANdisco Subversion Server".
When I create a new repository using the

```
svnadmin create C:\svn\repositories\MyNewRepository
```

command, I can't browse the new repo in the repo-browser or via web browser until I manually restart the "WANdisco Subversion Server" service in the Services Control Panel.

Isn't the repository supposed to show up right away?  Is there something we have set up incorrectly or is there a setting I need to check?  I have inherited this source control solution from my predecessors, so I can't offer more details on the set up of SVN (unless you tell me where to look).

Comment: Sorry, but you should learn your setup and not just say "I have inherited this." Anyway, is a restart of the service the only thing you do after adding a repo?

Comment: I never said that I was not willing to "learn my setup".  I'm just saying that I didn't set up the environment, so I don't know what's even relevant about the set up unless people ask.  Plus, I am not the one responsible for choosing the technology that we are using, so I can't do things like switch to CollabNet or Visual SVN Server on a whim.

Comment: To answer your question - I am creating the repository, editing the subversion.conf file, editing the svn-acl file, and then restarting the WANdisco Subversion Server service.  At that point, the repository shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Repositories show up right away on the CollabNet Subversion service I have running on Windows XP.  No special settings were needed.

Start with the [Red Bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  Also think about trying a client like [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/).

Update:

Instead of doing this:

> svnadmin create C:\svn\repositories\MyNewRepository

Why not try creating a new repository using Tortoise?  Perhaps that will work better for you.

Comment: Yes, I have the Red Bean book and I am using TortoiseSVN.  Are you suggesting that I run CollabNet instead of WANdisco?  It's not clear what you are suggesting.

Comment: I'm saying that CollabNET is working perfectly for me without a restart.  It's up to you whether or not you want to change.

Comment: I just tried creating the repo using TortoiseSVN and it didn't automatically show up.

According to this doc (http://svn.spears.at/) you need to restart Apache to re-read the subversion.conf file.  BTW, I am manually editing the subversion.conf file and the svn-acl access control list file before restarting.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you Visual SVN Server. It's a simple setup for Windows boxes, works with Apache underneath, allows you to work via HTTPS and has integrated windows user authentication. And the free version is fully functional. It makes repositories maintenance as simple as possible, you just have to click around.